# How to make counter that counts zeros?

Tags: arrays, c, counter

I have 4 elements, let's say p1, p2, p3, p4. They all can have value 0 or anything but 0. (low and high). I need counter that equals 4. When any of those elements is high counter should do -1.
For example the user enters following values: p1=0, p2=1, p3=1, p4=0. Final value should be 2.
So I tried it with array of 4 elements, and one counter that decreases value every time one element is not 0 (It's high).
This code only works when i have all 0 or all high. What can i change?

```
int main()
{
    int array[4]={0,0,0,0};
    
    printf("Enter value p1:");
    scanf("%d", &array[0]);
    
    printf("Enter value p2:");
    scanf("%d", &array[1]);
    
    printf("Enter value p3:");
    scanf("%d", &array[2]);
    
    printf("Enter value p4:");
    scanf("%d", &array[3]);
    
    int i=4;
    int j=0;
    if (array[0]!=0)
    {
      j++;
        
        if(array[1]!=0)
            {
                j++;
            
            if (array[2]!=0)
            {
                j++;
                
                if (array[3]!=0)
                {
                    j++;
                }
            }
            } }
    int z=i-j;
    
    printf("%d", z);
```

Comment: Please show us your code if you want help with your code.

Comment: Please include code as text in the question ([formatted in a code block](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)), not as a link to an image which nobody can copy/paste for testing.

Comment: Code as text not images

Comment: 1. Check the return value from `scanf` - see the manual page. 2. If you do not have a new line in `printf` then add `fflush(stdout)` afterwards so it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a for loop, instead of a nested if :

```
for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++){
  
   if (array[index] != 0){

       j++;

     }

}
```